# Не запускается эмулятор в Android Studio | emulator process for ... was killed

Tags: java, android

Не запускается эмулятор через Андроид студию ни через AVD Manager , ни через запуск приложения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот сам лог:

```
Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_XL_API_22 was killed
```

Список того, что я уже сделал но оно никак не помогло:

1. Перезагружал ПК
2. Переустанавливал Android Studio
3. Установил Hardware Excecution Manager
4. Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer ) - установлен в SDK Manager'e

До этого у меня Андроид студия нормально работа на предыдущей ОС на этом же ПК. После переустановки Винды и установки Андроид Стиудии на новую винду такое вот и произошло.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Проверьте в **CMOS Setup**, включены ли VT-x, VT-d. AMD-V. Да, и во время запуска должно быть **не** запущены никакие другие виртуальные машины.

Comment: У меня UEFI от асус

Comment: У меня включена виртуализация

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed - может тут есть варианты решения :)

Comment: Точно такая же проблема "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_29 was killed." Выше перечисленные способы не помогают. У меня ноут на win10. Только установил. Запускаю пишет "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_29 was killed."???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Удалить AVD, создать новую.
2. В диспетчере задач удалить процесс adb32. Подождать немного, пока Андроид студио обновит данные по эмуляторам

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло отключение антивируса в windows 10

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Еще может быть проблема в видеокарте.

По дефолту выставлен Automatic для графики. Его можно попробовать поменять на Software. Проблема в том, что для Google APIs образов эта настройка не меняется, но ее можно сменить в `%homepath%\.android\avd\<AVD-name>\config.ini`

Находим строки

```
hw.gpu.mode=auto
```

меняем на

```
hw.gpu.mode=off
```

При этом эмулятор будет не так быстр как хотелось бы, но хотя бы запустится.

ЗЫ Еще драйвера видеокарты обновить не помешает.

Answer (score -1):

К сожалению такое происходит. Под Windows очень часто возникают проблемы с запуском "родного" эмулятора. Единого рецепта нет. Есть только разные хинты:

1. Использование не родного эмулятора - например, очень хорошо себя показывает [Genmymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)
2. При прочих равных условиях эмулятор с Google APIs работает хуже, то есть если возможность надо стараться использовать версии без Google APIs
3. Часто возникают проблемы при использовании эмулятора с видео с hardware acceleration, к сожалению альтернатива - еще хуже, видео без hardware acceleration - сразу означает потерю скорости
4. Кардинально важно иметь достаточное количество RAM - опять таки по опыту менее 8 гигов - это уже приговор.

Радикальное решение - это "уход" на Linux, MAC OS или даже на Chrome OS. Их установка (самих ОС) иногда выливается в специальную проблему, зато после корректной установки - все летает и компиляция и особенно эмулятор(ы).

Answer (score -1):

Мне лично помогло следующее, переустановил Андроид студию и в мануальном режиме увеличил кол-во оперативной памяти которой может пользоваться эмулятор. Почему то по дефолту стояло всего 2 Гига.

Comment: ¿Где это там такая настройка?

Comment: При установке в мануальном режиме по мимо пути установки и прочего был шаг где можно было выбрать сколько оперативной памяти может использовать эмулятор.

Comment: Это не Android Studio, а настройки Intel HAXM. Для их изменения саму AS нет нужды перустанавливать, достаточно только HAXM.