# Emulator procces for AVD was Killed

Tags: android

я переустановил windows, установил андроид студио при запуске android emulator , у меня выходит ошибка android emulator wass killed
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я все погуглил перепробовал все ответы, на stackoveflow . ничего не помогает как быть?...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не запускается эмулятор в Android Studio | emulator process for ... was killed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1190491/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2-android-studio-emulator-process-for-was-killed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое часто бывает, когда на диске С:\ остается меньше 3-7 гигов. Освободите место или:

1. Перейдите в папку `C:\Users\%user%\.android\avd`
2. Переместите папку с эмулятором на диск, где есть достаточно места
3. Откройте в оригинальной папке `ini` файл и отредактируйте путь до места эмулятора.
4. (необязательно, но желательно) Перезагрузите Android Studio.