# Android Studio: Error running 'myProject': The application could not be installed

Tags: android, android-studio

Моё приложение не запускается на эмуляторе и реальном устройстве через USB, при этом нет никаких подробностей ошибки. Я попробовал все советы, которые нашёл на ~20 страницах поисковика, но ничего не помогло. При этом .apk отлично собирается и работает, если установить его отдельно.

[image: Вот так выглядит ошибка]

Я менял порты adb, я менял флаги и параметры запуска, я чистил кэш, я переустановил Windows. Ничего не помогло. Может, у кого-нибудь есть идеи?..

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не запускается эмулятор в Android Studio | emulator process for ... was killed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1190491/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2-android-studio-emulator-process-for-was-killed)

Comment: шаг попробовать использовать другое устройство. шаг 2 попробовать использовать другой компьютер - так можно хотя бы узнать проблему

Comment: Неужели во вкладке Run никаких логов нет?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в том и беда, что абсолютно